# How to uninstall label studio?

Tags: linux, docker, uninstallation

I accidentally installed label studio in a wrong directory using the follow command:

`` docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest ``

Is there any way to uninstall or remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did `pwd` have anything else except for what the image installed? If not, simply delete the container and the contents that was created on your main filesystem.

If you did have something in the `pwd` and the contents mixed, this is a bit trickier. You can create an empty directory, then run the image in the empty directory. After finishing you can see what directories and files got created and compare with the `pwd` one by one.

Comment: There is a folder created but it can be removed. It produces this error: `Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir'...'`

Comment: Maybe the docker image created it with `root` as owner. Use `sudo` when deleting.

Comment: Alternatively, you can first change the owner to your user and then delete it: `sudo chown -R myusername directory`, then you should be able to delete it.

Comment: In case you don't have sudo, you can also use `su` typed as a single command. This will log you in as root.

Comment: Thanks, the sudo thing worked. But since I'm new to the docker thingy, I'm just wondering if the docker image is created only once in the root folder? So, I did `docker image ls` in both the wrong and right directory and the result has the same image ID. So, if I remove the image, does it mean it will impact all of it?

Comment: The docker image is created once, but each time you run it it creates a container on the fly. If the container is finished, you can list it with `docker container ls -a`. If the problem is solved, you could mark the answer as such by clicking on the accept button (left hand side) :)

Comment: Sure, so what does it mean when we delete the docker container?

Comment: I believe what you did above is just delete a directory. The container and the image simply use the directory, they are not "in" the directory.

Comment: In general, the docker image is a blueprint and you create multiple containers from it. "Running" the image means actually create a new container and run it. You can delete the containers if you don't need them anymore. But for more information really look into the docker tutorials, this is not the right place for very basic information.